# how to use jquery in php without using external .js file in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have created a datepicker for my wordpress admin menu. So far I implemented it with external js buy now I want to use jquery inside my plugin's php file itself. I don't want to declare in any external .js files. Please help me... I looked for the solutions in google but I am unable to understand as I am a beginner..

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_menu', function()
{
$hook = add_menu_page( 
    'Date Pick', 
    'Date Pick', 
    'manage_options', 
    'sub-page-date-picker',
    function() { 
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">';
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">';
        echo '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>';
        echo '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>';
        echo '<form action="" method="post" id="dateform">'; 
        echo '<h1>Date Pick</h1>'; 
        echo '<div id="datepicker" class="datepickerclass"></div>';
        echo '<div id="DatePickerHidden"></div>';
        echo '<div id="feedback"></div>';
        echo '<input type="submit" id="submitform" name="submit" value="submit">';
        echo '</form>';
    }
);
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function( $hook )
{
    if( 'toplevel_page_sub-page-date-picker' !== $hook )
        return;
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'field-date-js', 
        plugins_url( '/ft.js', __FILE__ ), 
        array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-datepicker'), 
        time(), 
        true
    );
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-datepicker');
   });
   }); 
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 ?>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to paste the jquery code into your file? It's too big for that I think. Or do you mean you want to have jquery as a local file on your filesystem?

Comment: I want to paste my jquery into my php file. When inserted the jquery in script tag its showed error '' uncaught referenceerror: jquery is not defined" pls help me. I hav to complete this by today